# Protonmail-bridge install fails with unmet dependencies ttf-dejavu

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, fonts, 20.10

I'm trying to install the [protonmail-bridge](https://protonmail.com/bridge/install) (so that I can get and send my Protonmail via Thunderbird) on my new Ubuntu 20.10 install. Unfortunately it states it has unmet dependencies: `ttf-dejavu`. Anybody got a tip how to correct this?

```
***@***:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install ./protonmail-bridge_1.4.5-1_amd64.deb 
[sudo] password for ***: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'protonmail-bridge' instead of './protonmail-bridge_1.4.5-1_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 protonmail-bridge : Depends: ttf-dejavu but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

`ttf-dejavu` is a transitional package which was dropped from the archive in Ubuntu 20.10. The maintainers of `protonmail-bridge` should have replaced that dependency with `fonts-dejavu` long ago.

To solve the problem for now you can [download the focal version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/ttf-dejavu) of

```
ttf-dejavu
ttf-dejavu-core
ttf-dejavu-extra
```

Then install the two latter first:

```
sudo dpkg -i ttf-dejavu-*
```

And then do:

```
sudo apt install ./ttf-dejavu_2.37-1_all.deb
```

Comment: Thank you. I got an anwser from the protonmail-bridge team whitch is mostly the same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

From the protonmail-bridge team:

Thank you for flagging this. We're aware of this issue, and we're working on a fix.

For now, a workaround would be to download and install ttf-dejavu and its dependencies manually. They will act as metapackages, satisfying bridge's dependency on ttf-dejavu, while installing your distribution's own fonts-dejavu package.

Download these packages (from Debian sid):
https://packages.debian.org/sid/ttf-dejavu
https://packages.debian.org/sid/ttf-dejavu-core
https://packages.debian.org/sid/ttf-dejavu-extra

Download using the "all" Architecture and then select a mirror. After downloading the packages, install them using apt:

$ sudo apt install /path/to/download/location/ttf-dejavu*.deb